# Use built-in PropTypes for some Elements

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

How I could reuse the propTypes of lets say an `input` element inside my `InputWrapper`.

For example:

```
class TextInput extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    theme: PropTypes.oneOf(['themeOne', 'themeTwo']),
    inputProps: ??? // I would like to use the built-in props for React.DOM.input
  }

  render() {
    return <div className={cx(this.props.theme)}>
      <input
        {...this.props.inputProps}
        type="text"
      />
    </div>
  }
}
```

Is there somewhere the propTypes definition for built-in Components, which I could reuse?

Answer (score 1):

not sure if I understand correctly, but you could just use:

```
class TextInput extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    theme: PropTypes.oneOf(['themeOne', 'themeTwo']),
    inputProps: PropTypes.shape({
      type: PropTypes.string,
      value: PropTypes.string // etc...
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <div className={cx(this.props.theme)}>
      <input
        {...this.props.inputProps}
        type="text"
      />
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: exactly, this is what I want to avoid. "Defining all the possible props by hand.."

Comment: instead, I would like to `re-use` the already built-in props if possible, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to validate the input props in the first place. When you pass them to `input`, it will validate them.

This is usually done like this:

```
static propTypes = {
    theme: PropTypes.oneOf(['themeOne', 'themeTwo']),
}

render() {
    const {theme, ...inputProps} = this.props;

    return <div className={cx(theme)}>
      <input
        {...inputProps}
        type="text"
      />
    </div>
}
```

React does not actually validate properties that are passed to native components. If you want to validate them, you will have to define the validator props yourself and reuse them.

Comment: true, but, we are using `eslint` it will produce annoying warnings and such, thats why I need the definition there.. ;)

Comment: To use `// eslint-disable-line` and such, is also not an option, then its better to define them all or a subset manually..

Comment: @webdeb Which rule? My example shouldn't produce warnings for using undefined props.

Comment: oh yes, you are right, but anyway, but I am more interested in the built-in propTypes definition.

Comment: @webdeb I don't think you can access the prop types for `input`. That means you would have to define them in one place yourself and then reuse.

Comment: Are you sure, cause I am not, thats why I am asking :)

Comment: @webdeb React does not actually use prop type validation at all for the native components. You can pass anything and the only validation you get is the validation from you browser if it exists. You can verify it [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/dom/stack/client/wrappers/ReactDOMInput.js).

Comment: I quickly looked into it, and I guess you are right, I'll give you both a up-vote, if you want you can create a proper answer based on your last comment I'll accept it, thank you!